# Determine how long the effect of x on y may last in time series data

Tags: regression, time-series, lags, intervention-analysis

I have a time series dataset that contains variable *x* and *y* per month (180 rows). *x* represents incidents that happen infrequently and y is a continuous variable. However, when there is some incident *y* sees a decline for *k* months afterwards.

Based on a linear regression model, I have found that x has a significant effect on *y* if I use a time lag of *n* months. But in this case I have set the number of lags myself and this is not very useful.

Therefore, I am interested in finding the value of *k* empirically from the data. That is to find **how long the effect of *x* on *y* may last?**

I would really appreciate any kind of help, especially if you could indicate what type of test would be useful here.